# How can I check whether a jQuery element is in the DOM or not?

Tags: jquery, function, dom, alert

My question is, how can I check whether jQuery element has been removed from the DOM or not?

Create one function and pass that element id and check, if it is available in DOM then remove it otherwise alert message.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property of jQuery object to check whether the element exists or not, and [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove it:

```
function check(selector){
  var elm = $("#"+selector)
  if(elm.length)
    elm.remove();
  else
    alert("does not exist");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var abc=function(efg)
{
 if($('#'+efg).length)
  $('#'+efg).remove();
  else 
  alert("your message");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could

```
$("#id").remove().length || alert("not found");
```

Answer (score 1):

For Example
Like this:

```
if (!jQuery.contains(document, $foo[0])) {
    //Element is detached
}
 else
 alert("your message");
```

This will still work if one of the element's parents was removed (in which case the element itself will still have a parent).